# Как сделать зависимость между кнопкой и option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в зависимости от выбранной опции тега select, содержащей data-id, привязать его к кнопке, т.е при выборе 1, кнопка получала data-id = 1 и тд. И при клике кнопка выполняла бы функцию?

Answer (score 1):

Из option всё-таки логичнее получать value, чем какие-то data-id. А уже эти value присваивать атрибуту кнопки:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  $('button').attr('data-id',$(this).val())
  $('button').text('Кнопка: data-id="'+$(this).val()+'"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
</select>

<button data-id="">Кнопка</button>
```